# Issues With MongoDB storage (9001 already in use)

Tags: mongodb

I am getting this error when trying to run the command
`mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T11:23:41.733-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T11:23:41.733-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T11:23:41.734-07:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
```

I do see the issue is
`"attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}`

But I don't know how to resolve this?

I tried other suggestions from another SO post that says to kill the process and restart. I did that and it did not work for me.

I also tried running mongod on a different port

```
mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb --port 27019
```

which gives me this error

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T11:27:29.535-07:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /var/lib/mongodb"}}
```

So it's a read only directory so I ran

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mongodb
```

Then I get this error in the log

```
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /var/lib/mongodb directory"}}
```

So I try to find out which other process is running

```
ps -eaf | grep mongod

mongodb   722732       1  0 11:09 ?        00:00:10 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
srt       725772  720106  0 11:34 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mongod
```

But idk what to do from here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have already the default auto started mongod instance running that use the default /etc/mongod.conf file
You may stop this instance via:

```
  service mongod stop
```

or

```
  kill -2 722732
```

or

```
 mongo --port 27017
 >use admin
 >db.shutdownServer()
```

or

```
 systemctl stop mongod
```

You can modify the /etc/mongod.conf file with your needs and start it again with

```
  service mongod start
```

or:

```
 systemctl start mongod
```

Comment: What is `kill -2 722732`? I would rather suggest `kill -2 $(pidof mongod)`

Comment: It is the pid taken from last: ps -eaf | grep mongod   :)

Comment: What do I modify in mongod.conf file? @R2D2

Comment: I also had to run the command as sudo since root ows the .lock file. Even if I change permissions on it and or delete it, when mongod restarts it recreates the file under `root` instead of my user

Comment: PA-GW: you may change many things in mongod.conf like listening port, storage engine, log file location, data location etc.

Comment: afcourse you may diaable the mongod default service and run your own instance in your user name space...

Comment: command not found:service

Answer (score 1):

I used ***sudo mongod*** then I got this error,
Now I type **sudo pkill -f mongod ** to get rid of this error and it worked,

Now again can use sudo mongod to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
    sudo pkill -f mongod 
    sudo mongod
```

this solved my issue in my ubuntu 22.04 system

Comment: and run     sudo mongod in terminal instead of mongod

Comment: you should  try **mongosh** instead of mongo in newer version of mongodb to launch it in terminal of ubuntu